# How to generate a unique ticket number using PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to generate unique ticket number for every booking add should generate one unique id
Ex:B0000000001

Comment: This question is too broad, and you would best be suited at googling the solution. StackOverflow is intended to help with specific issues, and generally require example code for us to analyse. Your question has a large number of possible solutions, so please look to google, or other resources, and make an attempt at solving your problem, then return here if you have any specific questions from your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `random_string` in Codeigniter

**Syntax**

```
random_string([$type = 'alnum'[, $len = 8]])
```

Available Types(`$type`) are

1. alpha -  A string with lower and uppercase letters only.
2. alnum - Alpha-numeric string with lower and uppercase characters.
3. basic - A random number based on mt_rand().
4. numeric - Numeric string.
5. nozero - Numeric string with no zeros.
6. md5 - An encrypted random number based on md5() (fixed length of 32).
7. sha1 - An encrypted random number based on sha1() (fixed length of
   40).

[Read More about `random_string`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html#random_string)

Comment: guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: use 16, will give you tons of result. Its better with text even. and simply if duplicate can create another.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$uniqueNumber = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");`
for generating unique number each time based on time.

Comment: this is easily guessable!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using str_pad

**Code**

```
$max = 9;
for($x = 1; $x <= 11; $x++){

    echo 'B' .str_pad('', $max - strlen((string) $x), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . $x . "<br />";
}
```

**Result**

```
B000000001
B000000002
B000000003
B000000004
B000000005
B000000006
B000000007
B000000008
B000000009
B000000010
B000000011
```